# Flash in powerpoint 2010

Tags: flash, powerpoint

I am trying to add a falsh file and set it so that it always run when I open my presentation slide show. What is killing me is that each time I open the power point or run the slide show for the first time, the next time the 'playing' setting will be false and the flash will not run untill I edit the setting again and make 'playing=true'. why the settings are not saved.
P.S. I am using power point 2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last time I had to embed Flash file in the PP presentation I had plenty of problems (one of them was similar to yours). I found a workaround (not perfect, but acceptable):

I created a simple HTML document containing my Flash file and used third party PP extension ([Live Web](http://skp.mvps.org/liveweb.htm)) to embed HTML in PP slideshow.